# Strange behavior while reading rows in DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

--- Complete Code basically i am just exporting a DataTable to Csv.

```
try
{
    DataTable dt_copy = new DataTable();
    dt_copy = records;

    string filePath = exportFileName;
    //DataTableToCsv(dt_copy, exportFileName);

    using (TextWriter sUrl = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        var columnNames = dt_copy.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(column = "\"" + column.ColumnName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")
            .ToArray();                
        sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", columnNames));
        int x = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in records.Rows) // Out of Memory Exception Here
        {
            x = x + 1; // This loop never stop rows are 32k and i has reached 3 million +
            var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field = "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
            sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
        }
    }

    if (MessageBox.Show("Open File", "Open Excel Sheet ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exportFileName);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Dont put in pictures, add the code and the complete error message + stacktrace

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is no error message it just keeps going on and on and on and on... and i have to stop it ..

Comment: Pls get the row count of  datatable at the beginning of the method. I suspect your datatable actually conains ~million records. If it has million rows, avoid using DataTable, instead use DataReader.

Answer (score 1):

You get the `OutOfMemoryException` probably because you are creating a lot of temporary objects there. Note that....

- `DataRow.ItemArray` creates a new `Object[]` for every row,
- `field.ToString` creates a new string for every field(object),
- `String.Replace` creates a new string for every other string,
- `ToArray` creates a new array of all replaced columns
- `String.Join` creates a `StringBuilder` and appends all columns of the array

If you just want to output the modified fields this is more efficient:

```
var columns = records.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
foreach (DataRow row in records.Rows)
{
    var newFields = columns.Select(c => $@"""{row.Field<string>(c)}""");
    sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", newFields));
}
```

This presumes that all columns are strings, otherwise it doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Any explanation of why did foreach exceeded table rows ?

Comment: @confusedMind: where did you mention that? **Edit** Ah i see, in the picture (remove it and mention it in your question). No idea, that should only be possible if you used the debugger

Comment: It did but even when you run the exe you see similar behavior . I will add break point manually for now...

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% sure. It is not a problem with `foreach`.

Kindly remove `var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field = "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
            sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", fields));` and check.

But if you still going this problem then check a condition to break the loop

```
int x = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in records.Rows) // Out of Memory Exception Here
    {
        x = x + 1;
        if(x > records.Rows.Length)
        {
          break; 
        }
        var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field = "\"" + field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"").ToArray();
        sUrl.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
    }
```

Comment: @confusedMind Yeah!  I hope **Tim Schmelter** answer will give that details.